# Change title of product fields in Opencart according to different languages

Tags: opencart

I am using **Opencart** with multi languages. My **Opencart Version** is **2.0.1.0**. I need to change the titles of product fields according to the selected language. For example, let say I have English and Spanish Language. when I add a new product in "English", Description field title is written as "Description". when I change my language to Spanish, the title remains same but I need to display it as "Descripción".

I have made changes in my product files in the language folder of the admin side.

// Entry

```
$_['entry_name']             = 'Product Name';
$_['entry_description']      = 'Descripción';
$_['entry_meta_title']       = 'Meta Tag Title';
$_['entry_meta_keyword']     = 'Meta Tag Keywords';
```

I expect the changed Title for Product Description Field on the Product page.

Comment: When you posting some question regarding OC please do not forget to tell whhich version you are using. In you case if you using OC3.x.x, seems enough in admin clear cache, blue gear icon in the right upper corner of the dashboard... and refresh modifications, and maybe clear browser cache by pressing ctrl+F5 twice.

Comment: Okay, I will take care this next time, my Opencart version is 2.0.1.0.

Comment: I hope you have created new translation to Spanish and placed it to corresponding Spanish language folder... you did so?

Comment: Yes, I have 4 languages but I currently it was required for only two languages, One for English and 2nd for Spanish. I have translate product headings in Spanish language under Spanish Language folder.

Comment: did you get some errors in error log? also the same lines you have in english language corresponding folder, just in english?

Comment: This would require some pretty big changes. You are editing the language files, but the admin area chooses one language to show to the admin, so you won't have multiple languages loaded onto a single template

Comment: Yes, I got this, to do this so, we have to change a lot of things not only in language folder but also in other folders like controller or views.